# Migrating from Apache to lighttpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd

There are many threads here weighing the various merits of Apache and lighttpd. However, no one has talked about tools for migrating from the former to the latter. Are there good tools for the task? I have a bunch of random .htaccess tweaks in directories around a site, I want to find them and make sure those are either converted cleanly or called out obviously for hand-massaging.

[[ Moved from Stackoverflow for content reasons ]]

Comment: Ouch! It is not going to be painless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few tools, as this is a pain to do in the trivial case, and in the more complex ones, well...  tools just won't cut it.

You may be able to run both in parallel while converting over though, on different ports.  That may help in the transition, but that's a methodology not a tool.

[This article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/migration-from-apache-to-Lighttpd) may be useful, and even mentions a tool that may work.  The article seems somewhat dated though.